Convert French spelled out numbers to integers
Given a string that is a number between 0 and 100 (included) spelled out in French, write a function (or a whole program) that outputs the corresponding integer.

List of all test cases :
zero                   ==>  0
un                     ==>  1
deux                   ==>  2
trois                  ==>  3
quatre                 ==>  4
cinq                   ==>  5
six                    ==>  6
sept                   ==>  7
huit                   ==>  8
neuf                   ==>  9
dix                    ==>  10
onze                   ==>  11
douze                  ==>  12
treize                 ==>  13
quatorze               ==>  14
quinze                 ==>  15
seize                  ==>  16
dix-sept               ==>  17
dix-huit               ==>  18
dix-neuf               ==>  19
vingt                  ==>  20
vingt-et-un            ==>  21
vingt-deux             ==>  22
vingt-trois            ==>  23
vingt-quatre           ==>  24
vingt-cinq             ==>  25
vingt-six              ==>  26
vingt-sept             ==>  27
vingt-huit             ==>  28
vingt-neuf             ==>  29
trente                 ==>  30
trente-et-un           ==>  31
trente-deux            ==>  32
trente-trois           ==>  33
trente-quatre          ==>  34
trente-cinq            ==>  35
trente-six             ==>  36
trente-sept            ==>  37
trente-huit            ==>  38
trente-neuf            ==>  39
quarante               ==>  40
quarante-et-un         ==>  41
quarante-deux          ==>  42
quarante-trois         ==>  43
quarante-quatre        ==>  44
quarante-cinq          ==>  45
quarante-six           ==>  46
quarante-sept          ==>  47
quarante-huit          ==>  48
quarante-neuf          ==>  49
cinquante              ==>  50
cinquante-et-un        ==>  51
cinquante-deux         ==>  52
cinquante-trois        ==>  53
cinquante-quatre       ==>  54
cinquante-cinq         ==>  55
cinquante-six          ==>  56
cinquante-sept         ==>  57
cinquante-huit         ==>  58
cinquante-neuf         ==>  59
soixante               ==>  60
soixante-et-un         ==>  61
soixante-deux          ==>  62
soixante-trois         ==>  63
soixante-quatre        ==>  64
soixante-cinq          ==>  65
soixante-six           ==>  66
soixante-sept          ==>  67
soixante-huit          ==>  68
soixante-neuf          ==>  69
soixante-dix           ==>  70
soixante-et-onze       ==>  71
soixante-douze         ==>  72
soixante-treize        ==>  73
soixante-quatorze      ==>  74
soixante-quinze        ==>  75
soixante-seize         ==>  76
soixante-dix-sept      ==>  77
soixante-dix-huit      ==>  78
soixante-dix-neuf      ==>  79
quatre-vingts          ==>  80
quatre-vingt-un        ==>  81
quatre-vingt-deux      ==>  82
quatre-vingt-trois     ==>  83
quatre-vingt-quatre    ==>  84
quatre-vingt-cinq      ==>  85
quatre-vingt-six       ==>  86
quatre-vingt-sept      ==>  87
quatre-vingt-huit      ==>  88
quatre-vingt-neuf      ==>  89
quatre-vingt-dix       ==>  90
quatre-vingt-onze      ==>  91
quatre-vingt-douze     ==>  92
quatre-vingt-treize    ==>  93
quatre-vingt-quatorze  ==>  94
quatre-vingt-quinze    ==>  95
quatre-vingt-seize     ==>  96
quatre-vingt-dix-sept  ==>  97
quatre-vingt-dix-huit  ==>  98
quatre-vingt-dix-neuf  ==>  99
cent                   ==>  100

Rules:

This is code-golf, so the shortest solution in bytes wins.
Input will always be well formatted (except for the accent) like above
There won't be an accent in zero to help with character encoding
Input must be in lower-case (because if not, there could be a loophole that allows to encode the number in the casing of the input)
No standard loopholes
Not allowed: using an external source such as a website, as well as any libraries or APIs, that convert from a text to a number in any language, or translate text between languages
Allowed: if a language happens to natively have a built-in function that helps with converting from text to number, or translate from one language to another, you can use it


“Vingt-et-un” needs hyphens as well as “trente-et-un”... since the reform of 6th december 1990.

Related

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), soixante-neuf octets
Interpreter["SemanticNumber"]@TextTranslation[#,"French"->"English"]&

Just to prove that there's always a builtin....

Damn, Mathematica is a beast!

It's magnificient! I hoped that there would be a right tool for this golfing job!

Funny bytecount… No it just makes me disgusted.

JavaScript (Node.js), 109 bytes
s=>s.replace(/(-v)?\w+/g,p=>t+=Buffer(`EX\\LJN@LAK(ROLdFMHDI~LLLpCGBL`)[parseInt(p,36)%847%272%30]^76,t=0)&&t

Try it online!
Method
The value of most French numbers in \$[0\dots100]\$ is the sum of the values of all parts, e.g. soixante-dix-sept is \$60+10+7=77\$.
So the basic idea is to isolate each word, parse it as base 36, apply some formula to get an index into a lookup ASCII string, get its value XOR'ed with some constant to avoid problematic characters, and eventually return the sum of everything.
The only exception is for quatre-vingts and all numbers of the form quatre-vingt-xxx where quatre-vingt(s) has to be interpreted as \$4\times20\$ rather than \$4+20\$.
We can handle this special case by matching the - when it precedes a v, thus turning -vingt and -vingts into negative values (in base 36) pointing out of the lookup table. By choosing \$76\$ for the XOR operation(*), they are evaluated to this value and we get the expected sum \$4+76=80\$.
(*) By a happy coincidence, this value takes us to the highest printable ASCII code \$126\$ (for \$50\$ XOR \$76\$) without exceeding it.
Lookup table
The modulo chain and the corresponding lookup table were found by running an exhaustive brute-force search for the pattern % m0 % m1 % m2 with:
$$m2 < m1 < m0 < 1000$$
applied to the 24 keys of the following dictionary parsed in base 36:
{"et":0,"zero":0,"un":1,"deux":2,"trois":3,"quatre":4,"cinq":5,"six":6,"sept":7,"huit":8,"neuf":9,"dix":10,"onze":11,"douze":12,"treize":13,"quatorze":14,"quinze":15,"seize":16,"vingt":20,"trente":30,"quarante":40,"cinquante":50,"soixante":60,"cent":100}

See the best solution
Commented
s =>                   // s = input string
s.replace(             // replace in s:
  /(-v)?\w+/g,         //   look for words, optionally preceded by "-v"
  p =>                 //   for each part p,
  t +=                 //   add to t:
    Buffer(            //     the ASCII code of the character
      `EX...BL`        //     from the lookup string
    )[                 //     at the position obtained by:
      parseInt(p, 36)  //       parsing p in base 36
      % 847 % 272 % 30 //       and reducing it with this modulo chain
    ]                  //
    ^ 76,              //     XOR'ed with 76
  t = 0                //   start with t = 0
)                      // end of replace()
&& t                   // return t


Nice answer! For information, i edited the input in the challenge so that each " et " now becomes -et-, and i made sure beforehand that your code still works with these modified input

Retina 0.8.2, 137 bytes
ce
100
e-v|so
60
nqu
50
ar
40
en
30
g
20
sei
16
inz
15
rz
14
rei
13
uz
12
on
11
di
10
ne
9
h
8
p
7
si
6
nq
5
re
4
oi
3
ux
2
un
1
\d+
$*
1

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation: "Unique" substrings of each number are replaced by their value, which is then summed. (Some substrings depend on earlier replacements.) The exception is for quatre-vingt which is replaced by quatr60in20t thus totalling 80. I chose the substrings by hand so they may not be optimal.

Nice answer! For information, i edited the input in the challenge so that each " et " now becomes -et-, and i made sure beforehand that your code still works with these modified input

Google Sheets, 111 bytes 231 bytes
=match("*"&A1&"*",map(sequence(101),lambda(n,substitute(googletranslate(bahttext(n-1),"th","fr")," ","-"))),)-1

Uses the built-in bahttext() to convert numbers 0–100 to currency expressions in Thai so 99 gets "เก้าสิบเก้าบาทถ้วน". Then applies googletranslate() to get those expressions in French, and replaces spaces with dashes. Finally, finds the index of the input in the array thus created. Note that the formula uses the correct accented spelling of "zéro".

The screenshot shows Thai currency expressions and their French translations, but those columns are for demonstration only. Thanks to jdt and Klumpy7.
Here's an "honest" version that doesn't use built-ins (227 bytes):
=let(k,split("u0d0t0q0c0s0se0h0n0di0o0do0tre0quato0qui0sei0v0tren0quar0cinqu0so00b00ce",0,,),sum(map(split(regexreplace(A1,".+-v","b"),"-"),lambda(p,max(ifna(sort(hlookup(left(p,len(k)),{k;column(A:P),10*column(B:J)},2,))))))))

The same in JavaScript V8 (243 bytes, non-competing):
(t,k='0u0d0t0q0c0s0se0h0n0di0o0do0tre0quato0qui0sei0v0tren0quar0cinqu0so0b0ce'.split(0),v=[...Array(17).keys(),20,30,40,50,60,80,100])=>t.replace(/.+-v/,'b').split('-').map(p=>v.findLast((_,i)=>p.match(RegExp('^'+k[i])))||0).reduce((a,c)=>a+c)

Try it online (with findLast() polyfill.)

I assume that you already tried to use the GOOGLETRANSLATE function, but it returns the number as text, eg "three" and I can't figure out how to convert it to an integer without using a lookup table:
=IF(A1="un",1,GOOGLETRANSLATE(A1,"fr","en"))
But now that I think about it, any such function in Google Sheets could possibly convert the text to a number from French directly, especially if locale was set to French or something

You can convert a number to text in many languages through bahttext() and googletranslate(), but there is no built-in to do it the other way around.

You can use this to convert any number to french, well sort of.. =LET(a,GOOGLETRANSLATE(BAHTTEXT(55),"th","fr"),LOWER(LEFT(a,FIND(" b", a)))). You should then be about to write a REDUCE or something to generate them from 0 to 100 and see which one matches the input.

@jdt thanks. Contrary to my expectations, that approach saves quite a few bytes.

I'm on mobile and can't test it but I don't think the sort is necessary.

sort() was required to make row() array-enabled, but yes, using sequence() without array-enabling instead saves two bytes. Using &"*" in match() saves another three.

Python 2, 109 bytes
Since my Python golfing skills are close to zero, this can probably be improved.
lambda s:sum(ord("LML\RBDLHLKpEJOL@XFd(LNAL~GIC"[hash(p)%508%298%30])^76for p in s.split("-"))+56*(s[7:]>"v")

Try it online!
Method
This is similar to my JS answer with a simpler (but longer) fix for the quatre-vingt(s) special case. We just add \$56\$ if the 8th character of the input string is a 'v', which gives:
$$4+20+n+56=80+n$$
The extra bytes introduced with this explicit test are offset by the terser Python syntax for the lookup code.

Welp, there goes my answer.

05AB1E, 69 bytes
.•2{ε8∍'*.rΛÅËD/Ƶ.<”g×δ€À¦„QĀmÃ•ð'-:•l×{ñrÄ•4в£16L6YŸT*Ć«тª{R:A'-ª¡þO

Port of @Neil's Retina answer, so make sure to upvote that answer as well!
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
.•2{ε8∍'*.rΛÅËD/Ƶ.<”g×δ€À¦„QĀmÃ•
              '# Push compressed string "cee vsonquarengseiinzrzreiuzondinehpsinqreoiuxun"
  ð'-:        '# Replace the space with a "-"
•l×{ñrÄ•       # Push compressed integer 51582484503210
  4в           # Convert it to base-4 as list: [2,3,2,3,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]
    £          # Split the string into parts of those sizes
16L            # Push a list in the range [1,16]
   6YŸ         # Push a list in the range [6,2]: [6,5,4,3,2]
      T*       # Multiply each by 10: [60,50,40,30,20]
        Ć      # Enclose, append its own head: [60,50,40,30,20,60]
         «     # Merge the two lists together
          тª   # Also add an 100
            {R # Sort it in descending order
:              # Replace all substrings in the (implicit) input with those integers
 A             # Push the lowercase alphabet
  '-ª         '# Convert it to a list of characters, and append "-"
     ¡         # Split the string on those characters
      þ        # Remove all empty strings by only keeping numbers
       O       # Sum those integers together
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)

See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?, How to compress large integers?, and How to compress integer lists?) to understand why .•2{ε8∍'*.rΛÅËD/Ƶ.<”g×δ€À¦„QĀmÃ• is "cee vsonquarengseiinzrzreiuzondinehpsinqreoiuxun"; •l×{ñrÄ• is 51582484503210; and •l×{ñrÄ•4в is [2,3,2,3,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2].

Python 2,  324   302   278  276 bytes
-22 bytes by shrinking the multiples-of-10-ish prefixes.
-22 bytes by Lucenaposition.
-2 bytes by using the enumerate(iterable, start) form.
-2 bytes by Lucenaposition.
lambda x:g(x)[0]+max([0]+[i for i,s in E('er un ux is at nq si ep h f di on uz rei rz qui sei -s -h -n'.split())if s in g(x)[1].strip('-')])
g=lambda x:max([(0,x)]+[(i*10,x[x.find('-')+i/8*7:]*('-'in x))for i,p in E('v en ar nqu xa F -v F ce'.split(),2)if p in x])
E=enumerate

Try it online!

Charcoal, 86 bytes
≔⁻Ｓ-θ≔Ｉ⁺…¹¦¹⁷×χ⊕⪪1234559¹υＦ⪪”↶↖↑﹪ς4ＥＩ；�ζ⊗«ＪＫê'″.﹪⧴∨(WL4{Ｚ=≔M⟲´←<⦄◧¦↗↥1⌊f↶” ≔⪫⪪θι⊟υθＩΣθ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
≔⁻Ｓ-θ

Remove -s from the input. This makes the lookup string of replacements more compressible. (It also works around a behaviour change on ATO which would otherwise interpret them as negative numbers in Sum.)
≔Ｉ⁺…¹¦¹⁷×χ⊕⪪1234559¹υ

Make a list of the numbers 1..16, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 60, 100. (Note that the Cast is not necessary on ATO as Join automatically casts its second parameter to string.)
Ｆ⪪”...” 

Loop through a compressed list of substrings ce ... un. (See my Retina answer.)
≔⪫⪪θι⊟υθ

Replace each substring with its "value".
ＩΣθ

Output the total value.

Jelly, 47 bytes
⁵Ḋ×;⁴Ż¤“⁽²ṣỴȮ⁽ɱ?ẸỤ⁵’œ?ṭ“Ç+Zḷ’
ḟ”sṣ”-¢ḥⱮ60Ṗẹ¥¦4S

A monadic Link that accepts one of the \$101\$ lists of characters and yields the integer it represents.
Try it online! Or see all of them.
How?
Evaluate the '-' delimited parts by hashing. Convert "et" (as well as "zero") to \$0\$, and convert any leading \$4\$ found for "quatre" to \$60\$, then sum these values.
⁵Ḋ×;⁴Ż¤“⁽²ṣỴȮ⁽ɱ?ẸỤ⁵’œ?ṭ“Ç+Zḷ’ - Helper Link, GetSeedAndDomain: no arguments
⁵                             - Set the left argument to Ten -> 10
 Ḋ                            - dequeue -> [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  ×                           - multiply by {10} -> [20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
      ¤                       - nilad followed by links as a nilad:
    ⁴                         -   16
     Ż                        -   zero-range -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
   ;                          - concatenate
                                 -> DomainValues = [20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
       “⁽²ṣỴȮ⁽ɱ?ẸỤ⁵’          - base-250 number -> 135924907825578762729734134
                    œ?        - Permutation of {DomainValues} at {that} lexicographic index
                                  -> Domain = [100,11,30,12,5,70,2,60,50,4,16,10,80,13,7,20,3,9,14,8,1,6,15,90,0,40]
                       “Ç+Zḷ’ - base-250 number -> Seed = 237147969
                      ṭ       - {Domain} tack to {Seed}
                                  -> [237147969, [100,11,30,12,5,70,2,60,50,4,16,10,80,13,7,20,3,9,14,8,1,6,15,90,0,40]]

ḟ”sṣ”-¢ḥⱮ60Ṗẹ¥¦4S - Main Link, Translate: list of characters, S
ḟ”s               - filter out 's' characters (aligns "vingts" and "vingt")
   ṣ”-            - split at '-' characters -> Parts
      ¢           - call the Helper Link (above) -> SeedAndDomain
       ḥⱮ         - map across {Parts} performing Jelly's hash with {SeedAndDomain} -> HashedValues
              ¦   - sparse application...
             ¥ 4  - ...to indices: last two links as a dyad - F(HashedValues, 4):
           Ṗ      -                  pop (remove the rightmost part)
            ẹ     -                  indices of {4} -> [1] if representing 80-99
                                                    or [] otherwise
         60       - ...action: replace with 60
                S - sum

Note that the Domain includes three unused values - \$70\$, \$80\$, and \$90\$ - so improvement might be possible with a much higher Seed (“Ç+Zḷ’ \$= 237147969\$), although there would also be some overhead constructing the smaller list of DomainValues since \$100\$ is needed.

Excel ms365, 97 bytes
=XMATCH(A1,LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSLATE(BAHTTEXT(ROW(1:101)-1),,"fr"),"(é)| ","${1:+e:-}")),3)-1

This is making use of conditional string replacement through the PCRE2 engine available with REGEXREPLACE() and the new option in XMATCH() to match through a regular expression.

What version of excel are you running? I don't have REGEXREPLACE or TRANSLATE Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20160) 64-bit

@jdt, I'm currently on beta-channel. That's probably the difference.
